# How to set each individual matrix value depending on condition in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I want to create a matrix based whose values depend on an element wise comparison between two other matrix. For example:

I want C to have value 1 when A > B and 0 otherwise:

I've found a solution by exploiting the behaviour of tf.math.divide_no_nan and using some math:

```
(condition / condition) * result_if_true + (1 - condition / condition) * result_if_false
```

Which translates to this in tensorflow:

```
tf.math.add(tf.math.multiply(tf.math.divide_no_nan(condition, condition), result_if_true), tf.math.multiply(tf.math.subtract(tf.constant(1, tf.float32, matrix_shape), tf.math.divide_no_nan(condition, condition)), result_if_false))
```

But this seems so convoluted that I'm sure there must be a proper way to solve this. I've tried using tf.cond but it does not work for me as I need the condition to be evaluated element-by-element.

Here is what I want to accomplish following the example I presented at the start of the question:

```
A = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0]])
B = tf.convert_to_tensor([[3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0]])
C = #Solution goes here
print(C.run())
```

Result:

```
[[0,0],
[1,1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.where is the solution I was looking for.